# Instalar spyder no python

Tags: python-2.7

Como instalo o spyder no python 2.7 ??
eu já tenho o pip instalado nos scripts do python e o easy_install.. com a ajuda dum amigo
mas nao sei como instalar o spyder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No **Linux**:

Para instalar o **spyder** usando o **pip**:

```
pip install spyder
```

Para atualizar o **spyder** já instalado com o **pip**:

```
pip install -U spyder
```

No **Windows**

Pelo **pip** vocês não vai conseguir instalar.

• Primeiro instale a dependencia PyQT4. Faça o download do **.exe** [aqui](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/download)

• Depois baixe o **.exe** do spyder do [aqui](https://bitbucket.org/spyder-ide/spyderlib/downloads)

Referencia: [link](http://pythonhosted.org/spyder/installation.html#installing-on-windows-xp-vista-7-8)

Comment: e para windows?

Comment: @StinRose, Editei a resposta com windows e inseri no final o  link do site do spyder onde tem toda a documentação e passo a passo de instalação

Comment: Muito Obrigada!!!!